# How to customize the map used on gmap module (node locations)

Tags: location, google-maps

When [gmap module](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) and [location module](http://drupal.org/project/location) are installed, there is a page called "node locations", which display all node with a location field (filled) in the site.

How can I customize the google maps parameters? I want to disable the satellite map (and options in top right), enable street view, and change the zoom widget..

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The google maps parameters can be changed in file: "sites/all/modules/gmap/js/gmap.js"

Here is the option I choose:

**Street View enabled**:

```
opts.streetViewControl = true;
```

**Satellite map disabled**:

```
opts.mapTypeControl = false;
```

**Zoom widget change**:

```
opts.zoomControl = true;
opts.zoomControlOptions = {}; 
opts.zoomControlOptions.style = google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE;
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to use the GMap Views plugin of the GMap module, the Views module and the GMap Macro Builder module (comes with GMap):

- Download and enable Views
- Enable GMap Macro Builder
- Navigate to the macro builder (/map/macro) and create a map with the
  options you desire
- Copy the GMap macro to a temp place (clipboard obviously)
- Create a new view
- Select 'Show content' of any type you prefer and configure the
  remaining options accordingly (you can always change them at a later
  stage anyway)
- Click 'Continue & edit'
- In the format section, select Gmap In the GMap settings, paste the
  gmap macro so the produced map will follow the desired configuration
- Customize the view further and save.

I hope the above is helpful.